# To compare 2 dataset by RowNo

Tags: c#

In the below code I have two datasets  which I want to compare the dataset and check whether it has difference.

- In first  dataset I have 3 columns  Empname, EmpID, RowNo
- In second dataset I have 3 columns Empname, EmpID, RowNo

In the both datasets RowNo is a constant column other two columns are dynamic, so I want to compare datasets using the below scenario:

```
    Dataset1:
    Empname,EmpID,RowNo
    AAA      E1    1
    BBB      E2    2
    CCC      E3    3

    Dataset 2:

    Empname,EmpID,RowNo
    AAA      E1    1
    DDD      E4    4
    EEE      E5    5
    BBB      E8    2
    CCC      E9    3
```

I want to compare Dataset 1 with Dataset 2 by RowNo So on compare it should return RowNo 2and 3 are modified.
So Anyone please help me to do this.

Code:

```
for (int i=0; i < dataset1.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
     if (!(dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["RowNo"] == dataset2.Tables[0].Rows[i]      ["RowNo"] )
     {
         return i;
     }
}
```

Comment: My first question is why are you using 2 data sets rather than 2 data tables?

Comment: @SimonPrice I thought that it would easy so i tried that.If Datatable how to compare it .

Comment: that's pretty much what you've done, but a long winded way around.

Comment: Also, might be worth ordering your data before you get it into the dataset or datatable

Answer (score 0):

something like this should help you get you on your way

```
dataset2.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("RowNum") == i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it (I'm sure there must be others and maybe simpler). First, you merge the 2 datatables in one, and group the data by rowno. After that, you just have to compare the datarows by group to check which ones are modified. Something like this:

```
DataTable dt3 = dt1.Copy();
dt3.Merge(dt2);
var grouped=dt3.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("RowNo"));

List<int> RowsModified = new List<int>();
foreach(var group in grouped)
{
     if (group.Count() > 1)
     {
           DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();

           foreach (var row in group)
           {
                if (dr["RowNo"] == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    dr = row;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!dr.ItemArray.SequenceEqual(row.ItemArray))
                    { 
                         RowsModified.Add(group.Key);
                         break;
                    }
                }
           }
      }
}
```

At the end,in RowsModified you'll have a list of the row numbers. Hope it helps.

Comment: From Above example RowNo 2 and 3 are modified as EmpID are different in 2and 3 in dataset2

Comment: Yes...I've tried with your sample data and this method returns the row numers 2 and 3 @user2432361